# Extract parts of a .txt file into a list using Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract numerical codes from a large text file and put them into a list. These codes all start with `'gameId':` followed by a space and ten numbers (e.g. '`gameId': 4725591545`)

Thus far this is all I have managed.

```
#create a variable for the path
recent_matches_index = "path/to/records/recent_matches_index.txt"

#create an empty list
game_id_list = []

#open the file, read it, recognise the id codes I
#want and append them to the empty list.
#removing the string should be easy enough later on
with open (recent_matches_index, 'rt') as my_data_file:
    for game_id in my_data_file:
        game_id = my_data_file.find("'gameId': **********")
        game_id_list.append(game_id)

#lets see if it worked
print(game_id_list)
```

This throws the error: `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'find'`

I have tried quite a few other things but I feel like they have been very wrong.

Ideally, I think I would also like to scrub the characters out of the list and only have the numerical values. These values should remain in the order in which they occur in the file.

example of what the list might look like:

```
game_id_list = [8403937582, 8402849381, 9604860905]
```

Evidently I'm new to python so explicit answers will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is an example of what is in my .txt file.

```
[{'leagueId': '5ae26d6d-c07a-3d29-ae0f-1ac9ca4a4f4a', 'queueType': 'RANKED_SOLO_5x5', 'tier': 'CHALLENGER', 'rank': 'I', 'summonerId': 'Sb5Y-1bZYeIItHXgNDS1U-PI0kgKF6_Wr2ZYBPqv95OKCOA', 'summonerName': 'RGE Inspired2', 'leaguePoints': 1556, 'wins': 254, 'losses': 186, 'veteran': True, 'inactive': False, 'freshBlood': False, 'hotStreak': False}, {'leagueId': '92edd520-fcf0-4e6b-b767-e3938a408d66', 'queueType': 'RANKED_FLEX_SR', 'tier': 'PLATINUM', 'rank': 'IV', 'summonerId': 'Sb5Y-1bZYeIItHXgNDS1U-PI0kgKF6_Wr2ZYBPqv95OKCOA', 'summonerName': 'RGE Inspired2', 'leaguePoints': 100, 'wins': 11, 'losses': 2, 'veteran': False, 'inactive': False, 'freshBlood': False, 'hotStreak': False, 'miniSeries': {'target': 2, 'wins': 0, 'losses': 0, 'progress': 'NNN'}}]
{'matches': [{'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4728220480, 'champion': 121, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595790394190, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4727511119, 'champion': 104, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595776780604, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4727366101, 'champion': 121, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595774913709, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4724700944, 'champion': 104, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595632344294, 'role': 'DUO_SUPPORT', 'lane': 'NONE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4724662512, 'champion': 163, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595629227345, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4724497303, 'champion': 203, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595627065458, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4722652071, 'champion': 104, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595530253160, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4709654115, 'champion': 875, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594854382037, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4709546735, 'champion': 113, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594850792558, 'role': 'DUO_SUPPORT', 'lane': 'TOP'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4706883023, 'champion': 121, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594723475884, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4703718275, 'champion': 121, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594551535462, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4703411360, 'champion': 245, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594509687989, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4703403465, 'champion': 245, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594506333259, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'},
```

Comment: (1) Please include a sample from the file. (2) File object does not have method `find`.

Comment: (1) I have added a sample of the .txt file. (2) I was attempting to adapt code I had seen with the 'find' command, I am not sure how else to go about this.

Comment: You have a JSON file. You should treat it as such: open and read with `json.load()`.

Comment: @DYZ This doesn't seem to work for me (NameError: name 'json' is not defined
). Will loading it as a JSON file allow me to grab specific parts of it with greater ease?

Comment: Apologies, @DYZ, had forgotten to import json but am now being told <AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'>

Comment: `load`, not `read`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay as you did not provide a file example at first I was thinking of a txt file so this was my first solution:

```
txt = """
Lorem ipsum 'gameId': 4725591545 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
,  'gameId': 5725591546 consetetur sadipscing elitr,
'gameId': 6725591547 sed diam
"""

output = []
start_pos = txt.find("'gameId': ") + len("'gameId': ")

if txt.find("'gameId': ") != -1:
    while True:
        output.append(txt[start_pos:start_pos + 10])
        if txt[start_pos:].find("'gameId': ") != -1:
            start_pos += txt[start_pos:].find("'gameId': ") + len("'gameId': ")
        else:
            break

print(output)
# ['4725591545', '5725591546', '6725591547']
```

But then you edited your question with an example (btw a really bad example cause there are missing brackets and commas) which is not a valid json format because of the `'` instead of `"`. So I had to modify your example a little bit. And this could be a solution:

```
import json

txt2 = """{'matches': [{'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4728220480, 'champion': 121, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595790394190, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4727511119, 'champion': 104, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595776780604, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4727366101, 'champion': 121, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595774913709, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4724700944, 'champion': 104, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595632344294, 'role': 'DUO_SUPPORT', 'lane': 'NONE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4724662512, 'champion': 163, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595629227345, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4724497303, 'champion': 203, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595627065458, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4722652071, 'champion': 104, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1595530253160, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4709654115, 'champion': 875, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594854382037, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4709546735, 'champion': 113, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594850792558, 'role': 'DUO_SUPPORT', 'lane': 'TOP'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4706883023, 'champion': 121, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594723475884, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4703718275, 'champion': 121, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594551535462, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4703411360, 'champion': 245, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594509687989, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}, {'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameId': 4703403465, 'champion': 245, 'queue': 420, 'season': 13, 'timestamp': 1594506333259, 'role': 'NONE', 'lane': 'JUNGLE'}]}"""

txt = json.loads(txt2.replace("'", '"'))
output = [x["gameId"] for x in txt["matches"]]
print(output)
# [4728220480, 4727511119, 4727366101, 4724700944, 4724662512, 4724497303, 4722652071, 4709654115, 4709546735, 4706883023, 4703718275, 4703411360, 4703403465]
```

Instead of using a string like I did you can use it with a file. If your example is really what was saved in the file, then you may have to tidy up your string at first.

**EDIT**

As you wrote you put your json content into a file and to use my example with `txt2 = Path/To/File` this will not work. the json modul works with json strings so what you have to do is to make the txt2 variable a json string. So you first have to open the file and then read the content. Then you have the json string the module can work with. Try this one:

```
with open("path/to/myTestFile", "r") as f:
    txt2 = f.read()
```

As we open the file with the `with` statement we dont need to close it later on.

Comment: I apologise, I am not familiar with JSON I didn't realise the extent to which the formatting was actually very useful. I will implement your solution now.

Comment: Have a try. If it does not work you may have to show us the entire file and of course the error message

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help. I must retire, but I will continue again tomorrow.

Comment: I'm struggling, as your example works, but I cannot translate this over into my code. I have identified that when I put txt2 in its own .txt file and try and call it using a variable e.g. txt2 = path/to/myTestFile it fails (JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)). Essentially I think when I implement your solution I'm failing to tell python that I want the file identified by the path, and not to try to manipulate the literal path. I hope I have explained this with some degree of clarity? It seems like an elementary error but I'm stuck.

Comment: I will edit my answer once again to explain what might go wrong with your attempt.

Comment: Here's where I am: L1 `with open("/path/to/myTestFile", "r") as f:` L2 `txt2 = f.read()` L3 `txt = json.loads(txt2.replace("'", '"'))` L4 `output = [x["gameId"] for x in txt["matches"]]` L5 `print(output)` Error: `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2)` - I thought I grasped the problem from your explanation but I'm still causing myself grief.

Comment: Most likely this error comes because you have more than one json dict in your file. If this is the case wrap them with brackets like this `[{...},{...}]` or try `txt2 = "[" + f.read() + "]"`. Then you have to change the output line to `output = [x["gameId"] for x in txt[0]["matches"]]`

Comment: The thing is I'm using your txt2 file because that way we are both 'singing from the hymn sheet', so I can't think that the file would be wrong at all. I will gladly spend some time working on this until it works or until I become completely stuck if you want to move onto other questions. Otherwise, you will essentially be babysitting my code for me. Once I get it to work I will of course mark your answer as correct.

Comment: As there is an error and I could not see your code and the file it is really hard for me to help you. can you use pastebin to show me your code and of course the file, then I will have a last try.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the difficulty. Give me a minute or two.

Comment: Ha, I guess I have found your problem. When you save your json content into the file DO NOT keep the three quotion marks around the entire thing. This is python specific for a multiline string. Just delete the `"""` in the beginning and at the end and it works fine for me.

Comment: You absolute legend.